# How to fix periodic notification not send issue

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-workmanager, periodic-task

I've a small app with a button to activate periodic notification (work manager periodic work request) that send a test notification every 15 minutes

Thing is when I press the button notification is instantly send but only once. Even if I wait 20,30 minutes or set time to +1hour, nothing more

MainActivity:

```
private void initNotification() {

    sendNotifButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            enableNotification();
        }
    })

   private void enableNotification(){
    NotificationWorker.scheduleReminder();
}
```

Notification worker:

```
private SharedPreferences preferences;
private String notifMessage = "Notification numéro : ";
private int notifNumber = 1;
public static final int notif_id = 1;

public NotificationWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    preferences.edit().putString("message", notifMessage).apply();
    preferences.edit().putInt("numero", notifNumber + 1).apply();

    sendNotification();

    return Result.success();
}

private void sendNotification() {
    String message = preferences.getString("message", null) + "" + preferences.getInt("numero", 50);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText(message);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(notif_id, builder.build());
}

public static void cancelReminder() {
    WorkManager instance = WorkManager.getInstance();
    instance.cancelAllWorkByTag("worker_tag");
}

public static void scheduleReminder() {
    PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder notificationWork = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationWorker.class,
            15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            //Set network connected required to periodicWorkRequest
            .setConstraints(new Constraints.Builder()
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build());
    PeriodicWorkRequest request = notificationWork.build();

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("worker_tag", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE , request);
}
```

}

This feature has to be implemented to a bigger project but I can't succeed to send notifications every 15 minutes

Comment: Can you share what's happening in your logs?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have strict time intervals, I'd recommend using AlarmManager instead of WorkManager for this case. Assuming that you want to have those notification shown even when the app is in the background state, try using [AlarmManager#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%2520long,%2520android.app.PendingIntent)) method.

Answer (score 0):

I was also not able to understand much about `enqueUniquePeriodicWork(...)` works, but a simple `enque(...)` was working for me.
I also had an additional requirement to be unique and only one instance of my `worker` class to be running at a time, so i wrote this small singleton class.The following code :

- can create a periodic work request for some worker `MyWorker.class`, scheduled to be run in no constraints for every 15 minutes
- has a handy `isMyWorkerRunning()` method which can return weather You worker is running or not. note that it will return true for [enqueued,running or blocked state](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkInfo.State.html#enum-values_1)
- Internally, its maintaining the `id` of a worker in running state in its own shared preferences, to handle insertion and checking. And using the request's unique `tag` at the time of removing.

```java
public class WorkersHandler {
    private static WorkersHandler INSTANCE = null;
    private static final String TAG = "WorkersHandler";
    private static final String PREF_KEY_MY_WORKER = "my_Worker";

    private static final String TAG_WORKER_REQ = "Worker_req";

    private WorkManager workManagerObj;
    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private WorkersHandler(Context ctx) {
        Context appCtx = ctx.getApplicationContext();
        this.workManagerObj = WorkManager.getInstance(appCtx);

        String prefName = "WORKER_HANDLER";
        this.pref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(prefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    public WorkersHandler getInstance(Context ctx) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new WorkersHandler(ctx);
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public boolean isMyWorkerRunning() {
        boolean isRunning = false;

        UUID someWorkerID = getUUID(PREF_KEY_MY_WORKER);
        WorkInfo workInfo = getWorkInfoForWorker(someWorkerID);

        if (workInfo != null) {
            WorkInfo.State state = workInfo.getState();
            if (state == WorkInfo.State.RUNNING || state == WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED || state == WorkInfo.State.BLOCKED) {
                isRunning = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            //do nothing, the  work request associated with the give uuid doesn't exist in androidOS
            // schedular. simply return false
        }

        return isRunning;
    }
    @Nullable private WorkInfo getWorkInfoForWorker(UUID uuid) {
        WorkInfo workInfo = null;
        try {
            workInfo = workManagerObj.getWorkInfoById(uuid).get();
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return workInfo;
    }
    private UUID getUUID(String key) {
        //will return uuid of either a previous Worker running, or a garbage uuid(if
        // preferences doesn't have a value
        String garbageID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        UUID generatedID = UUID.fromString(pref.getString(key, garbageID));

        return generatedID;
    }

    public void startMyWorkerSingleton() {
        if (isMyWorkerRunning()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "startSingleTonLogWorker: Worker already running, therefore return");
            //return;
        } else {
            PeriodicWorkRequest LogWorkerRequest = buildMyWorkerRequest();
            putUUID(PREF_KEY_MY_WORKER, LogWorkerRequest.getId());
            workManagerObj.enqueue(LogWorkerRequest);
        }
    }
    private PeriodicWorkRequest buildMyWorkerRequest() {
        Constraints.Builder constraintsBuilder = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiresCharging(false)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.NOT_REQUIRED)
                .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(false)
                .setRequiresStorageNotLow(false);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            constraintsBuilder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(false);
        }

        return new PeriodicWorkRequest
                .Builder(LogsWorker.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)//<-- My workerclass. replace with yours
                .setConstraints(constraintsBuilder.build())
                .addTag(TAG_WORKER_REQ)
                .build();
    }
    private void putUUID(String key, UUID uuidString) {
        //will put uuid in prefs
        Log.e(TAG, "putUUID: called for key" + key + "with uuid string" + uuidString);
        pref.edit().putString(key, uuidString.toString()).apply();
    }

    public void  stopMyWorker(){
        Log.e(TAG, "stopPeriodicNotifierService: called" );
        workManagerObj.cancelAllWorkByTag(TAG_WORKER_REQ);
        putUUID(PREF_KEY_MY_WORKER, UUID.randomUUID());
    }



    }
```